# Access the Array object using generic typings

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling with creating an interface that's based on another interface.
All went well until I came to the Array of Objects.

Let me explain, I have an 'Entity' which types how a document is saved in a database, for example for dogs:

```
export class DogsEntity {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  specifications: {
    breed: string;
    color: string;
  };

  toys: Array<string>;

  walks: Array<{
    location: string;
    time: number;
  }>;
}
```

---

Now, to create a 'table' for it, I have another typing which is the EntityScheme class, which contains columns. To add options and specifications for this table, you've to create scheme columns, where I have created the following typings:

```
export interface IColumnOptions<Type = 'string' | 'number'> {
  type: Type;
  array?: boolean;
}

// When type 'object'
export interface IColumnOptionsObject<Entity, P extends keyof Entity> extends IColumnOptions<'object'> {
  properties: {
    [X in keyof Entity[P]]: ColumnOptions<Entity[P], X>;
  };
}

// When type 'object' and 'array: true'
export interface IColumnOptionsArrayOfObjects<Entity, P extends keyof Entity> extends IColumnOptions<'object'> {
  array: true;
  properties: {
    [X in keyof Entity[P]]: ColumnOptions<Entity[P], X>;
  };
}

// Combine the options
export type ColumnOptions<Entity, P extends keyof Entity> =
  | IColumnOptionsObject<Entity, P>
  | IColumnOptionsArrayOfObjects<Entity, P>
  | IColumnOptions;

// Scheme columns
export type SchemeColumns<Entity> = {
  [P in keyof Entity]: ColumnOptions<Entity, P>;
};
```

---

To convert the DogsEntity to SchemeColumns, I have to do the following:

```
const columns: SchemeColumns<DogsEntity> = {
  name: {
    type: 'string',
  },
  age: {
    type: 'number',
  },

  // This is an object
  specifications: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      breed: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      color: {
        type: 'string',
      },
    },
  },

  // This is an array containing strings
  toys: {
    type: 'string',
    array: true,
  },

  // This is an array containing objects
  walks: {
    type: 'object',
    array: true,

    // Problems are here
    properties: {
      location: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      time: {
        type: 'number',
      },
    },
  },

  // This errors, because 'random_property' is not known as a key of Entity
  random_property: {
    type: 'string'
  }
};
```

Everything works well, except the Array which contains objects. I get the following error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'location' does not exist in type '{ [x: number]: ColumnOptions<{ location: string; time: number; }[], number>;
```

I've tried adding `[number]`, like so: `[X in keyof Entity[P][number]]`. But that didn't do the trick.

---

How can I access the keys of the object in the Array in my typings, so I can accomplish the above SchemeColumns?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my problem and think of a solution!

Comment: Please share types with errors. I mean share examples with expected errors and witk ok result

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks for your feedback! I've changed my question so it's more clear what the expected result is, what expected errors are and the error I'm getting!

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I answered my own problem.
The problem lies in the `Entity[P]` part. Typescript doesn't know what kind of type lies behind the key of the Entity.

After some more research, you can do conditional-based typing inside the interface. So I've made an extra type which does this for me, like so:

```
type PropertyKey<Entity, Key extends keyof Entity> = Entity[Key] extends Array<unknown> ? Entity[Key][number] : Entity[Key]
```

In short, what this does is check if `Entity[Key]` is of type Array. If so, the keys are found in the `Entity[Key][number]`. If not, the keys are found in `Entity[Key]`.

After applying that, the properties of `walk` now work!